Best practices for handling enterprise sales opportunities
Our sales team is moving to close more Enterprise deals, and as such, they're finding that creating Opps for each outlet (let's say there are 60 in a group) is tedious and time-consuming. How can we handle this in Salesforce without building some custom architecture and automation? Are there any best practices or solutions you've found to work for this situation?
Requirements:

Each opty should be related to a parent account (Enterprise level)
Each outlet within the opty should be related to an account created by our software
Reporting is done at the account (not parent account) level for sales, commission, etc.
Any plan change or churn of an outlet within a group needs to be noted individually and at the parent account level
CS teams need to be able to pull reports at the parent, business group, and individual outlet levels - some outlets cross parents (e.g. Outlet 1 is part of business group A and Enterprise group Z, but business group A is not in Enterprise group Z since they're different brands)

I'd like to avoid situations where our Enterprise sales reps are spending hours cloning optys and adjusting MRR values in each one, but have some kind of screenflow/automation that will handle this for them.
TIA

Free advice (since you came to this forum): hire someone to help you.
